# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Control_Type' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Dear Stackflow community!

I know this question comes like weekly but I could not find the right solution to my problem.

I am trying to write a function the read a raw file.

The code looks like this:

```
def read_raw(file_name):
   f = open(file_name, 'r')
   lines = f.readlines()
   header = lines[9].rstrip().split('\t')
   dicts = {}

   for x,y in enumerate(header):
       if y == 'FeatureNum'
           num_id = x
       elif y == 'ProbeName':
           probe_name = x
       elif y == 'gProcessedSignal':
           signal = x
       elif y == 'ControlType':
           Control_Type = x

   for l in lines[10:]:
       l = l.rstrip().split('\t')
       if l[control_type] == '0':
           dicts[l[num_id]] = {'FeatureNum': l[num_id],\
                               'ProbeName': l[probe_name],\
                               'gProcessedSignal': l[signal]}
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicts)
   df['Signal'].astype(float)
   return df
```

I think you can imagine how the raw looks like and what I want to take out from it!

Now the thing is, I want to can call all the files from my directory, call out the function and put it all into a list, something like this:

```
path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(path)
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt'))

array_list = []
for files in all_files:
    arrays = read_raw(files)
    array_list.append(arrays)
```

And then I got This:

```
if l[Control_Type] == '0':
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Control_Type' referenced before assignment
```

Is there a way to fix this problem? I also tried to put global for control_type before the dictionary but it also did not work.

I would preferably have it without global though since I've read that it could messed with your function though.

Thank you in advance and wish you a lovely evening here in Austria.

Comment: Hi PM 2Ring! How should I explain it more thoroughly? What do you want me to explain more? That would help me fix my indentation :D

Comment: I actually just changed the code a little bit and made it smaller but I will change it right away. Thx PM 2Ring

Comment: This is now the right code! I did not change that much actually only the names I kind of shortened it. the function works though. I am trying to write my own code to read Agilent Microarray raw files if that is helping you :D

Comment: ah I know where the problem is! I will edit it now. Thanks :D

Comment: This should now work :D

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me PM 2Ring

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the spelling? 'C' not 'c'? and 'T' not 't'? in `Control_Type`.

Because in the code I could see `control_type` and in the error I could see `Control_Type`.

Comment: Yes veri_pudcha_coder the 'control_type' was meant to be 'Control_Type' :D I changed it thank you :D

Comment: I know this question occurs very often but I could not find the solution of this type of problem. mostly the variable was out of the function and they try to solve with writing 'global' inside the function to the variable

Comment: In your code Control_Type is initialised only when a condition is satisfied. You will get this error if that condition is not satisfied. So declare the variable outside the loop/ condition